# Android : XMPP message format issue while receive message

Tags: android, xmpp, chat

I am facing issue while receiving a message via XMPP in Android.

Sending Message format like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message xmlns="jabber:client" to="33@xx.xx.xx" from="1014@xx.xx.xx" 
type="chat" mediaType="text">
<body>Hello</body>
<mediaType>text</mediaType>
<mediaUrl />
<thumbUrl />
<from_id>1014</from_id>
<user_profile_pic>http://www..</user_profile_pic>
<user_profile_name>XYZ</user_profile_name>
<uniqueID>xsFf2ifTszKVg11ogAlgziD1IwWjcJ</uniqueID>
</message>
```

But I got below format in Android XMPP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message to="33@xx.xx.xx" from="1014@35.166.209.154/a94o853phq" type="chat">
<body>Hello</body>
<thread>61242b7c-e843-45cf-a9ff-0383ebf60aeb</thread>
<mediaType xmlns="jabber:client" />
<mediaUrl xmlns="jabber:client" />
<thumbUrl xmlns="jabber:client" />
<user_profile_pic xmlns="jabber:client" />
<user_profile_name xmlns="jabber:client" />
<uniqueID xmlns="jabber:client" />
<from_id xmlns="jabber:client" />
</message>
```

Send Message Code :

```
DefaultExtensionElement extXMPPMessage = new DefaultExtensionElement("message", "jabber:client");
   extXMPPMessage.setValue("to", toUser);
   extXMPPMessage.setValue("from", fromUser);
   extXMPPMessage.setValue("body", message);
   extXMPPMessage.setValue("type", type);
   extXMPPMessage.setValue("mediaType", mediaType);
   extXMPPMessage.setValue("mediaUrl", mediaURL);
   extXMPPMessage.setValue("thumbUrl", thumbURL);
   extXMPPMessage.setValue("from_id", from_id);
   extXMPPMessage.setValue("user_profile_pic", user_profile_pic);
   extXMPPMessage.setValue("user_profile_name", user_profile_name);
   extXMPPMessage.setValue("uniqueID", uniqueID);

   Message msg = new Message();
   msg.setType(Message.Type.chat);
   msg.setTo(toUser);
   msg.setFrom(fromUser);
   msg.setBody(message);
   msg.addExtension(extXMPPMessage);
   chat.sendMessage(msg); //chat is Object of Chat class
```

I am able to receive a message in interface method:

```
@Override
public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
   Log.e(TAG, "ProcessMessage Message received " + message.toString());
}
```

I don't know what is an issue, I got perfect Body, Also I am a success to receive a message but mediaType, username, user profile every tag are getting empty, please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Which version of smack are you using?

Comment: Hi @SANAT, Smack version 4.1.4

Comment: what happens when you are passing message from android to android?

Comment: Facing same issue in Android to Android also

Comment: Please post your code for send msg and receiving msg

Comment: @SANAT, please check edited code, thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141870/discussion-between-mahesh-kavathiya-and-sanat).

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `jabber:client` in namespace like this :

```
new DefaultExtensionElement("message", "jabber:client");
```

So, when you receive it, you are getting `jabber:client` in `xmlns`.

If you want to pass data through `DefaultExtensionElement` then use like this :

```
DefaultExtensionElement extEenderName = new DefaultExtensionElement(
                    "msgSenderName", "");
            extEenderName.setValue("msgSenderName", "Sanat");
            msg.addExtension(extEenderName);
```

Don't pass `namespace` there. I used single `DefaultExtensionElement` for single value. Its working.

Don't pass to, from, body in `DefaultExtensionElement`. Just pass to, from, body in `Message` object. Then add separate extension for other things.

One suggestion for the other kinds of data is to just pass JsonObject as a String in body with your text content and other data like mediaType, mediaUrl etc.

Comment: OK, thank you for an answer, this is for sending but why I got the same response from iPhone and Web.? iPhone to a website and website to iPhone Chat is working fine.

Comment: Then you need to match the Message object to web/ios. You are actually only getting the namespace value in tag of message.

Comment: I already suggested you to pass JsonObject as a String in Body tag. It will be available easily on all platforms and easily parse the body data.

Comment: is there any issue with Message receiver codes? because I am using ChatMessageListener

Comment: Well I know it's good to pass JSON in the body. But now I can't change my structure as per web and iPhone team need to change structure so . :(

Comment: OK let me try with other ideas and let you know for the same, thank you

Comment: I am also suffering from same situation. for matching android and ios. I have used separate DefaultExtensionElement for all other keys and values pair. From Ios side you have to fetch key by debugging the code. We already implemented recently.

Comment: Well, I am not run code of sendMessage so I think there is not any issue with DefaultExtensionElement because I am just connecting XMPP and send a message from IOS or Web and check response.